# How to install Kafka producer in Private Container?

Tags: docker, apache-kafka

I've Docker environment with 2 types of Containers:

1. **Kafka Consumer (monitoring multiple Topics)**
2. **Non-Kafka Containers (total count:3)**

The containers under #2 category, are normal containers and doesn't have Kafka installed.

## How to produce topics and publish to Topics monitored at #1 Kafka Consumer?

I'm totally new to this tech stack, please guide me. (Refer to below image for understanding my requirement)

Examples of Containers under #2:
https://hub.docker.com/_/couchdb
https://hub.docker.com/r/vitess/orchestrator

[image]

Currently my yml file looks like this:

1. Kafka Consumer (Kafka + Zookeeper)
2. Kafka Client (total 3) => **Goal is to replace this with any other image type**

```html
version: '3'
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: 'confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:latest'
    container_name: zookeeper
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181

  kafka:
    image: 'confluentinc/cp-kafka:latest'
    container_name: kafka-server
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    environment:
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://:9092
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka:9092
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1

  kafka-client1:
    image: 'confluentinc/cp-kafka:latest'
    container_name: kafka-client1
    depends_on:
      - kafka
    command: bash -c "exec sleep infinity"

  kafka-client2:
    image: 'confluentinc/cp-kafka:latest'
    container_name: kafka-client2
    depends_on:
      - kafka
    command: bash -c "exec sleep infinity"
  
  kafka-client3:
    image: 'confluentinc/cp-kafka:latest'
    container_name: kafka-client3
    depends_on:
      - kafka
    command: bash -c "exec sleep infinity"
```